# Class must either be declared abstract or implement findViewById(int) using AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, listview, android-annotations

I'm trying to implement a ListView Activity using AndroidAnnotations and overriding ItemClick method. The build constantly fails showing the following error in the generated by AA class ValueItemView_: "Class ValueItemView_ must either be declared abstract or implement findViewById(int) method in HasViews." I've found many similar Q/As also here in StackOverflow but more of them weren't anyhow related to a project configured to work with AndroidAnnotations. Everything I've tried till now didn't finish with a successful build.

I've tried to implement findViewById(int) method in ValuesActivity but then it tells me that the method is declared as final so I'm not allowed to implement it there.

My code is as follows:

ValueItemView:

```
@EBean
public class ValuesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Value> values;

    @RootContext
    Context context;

    @AfterInject
    void initAdapter() {
        values = new ArrayList<Value>();

        this.values.add( new Value("Value1", "Class1"));
        this.values.add(new Value("Value2", "Class2"));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ValueItemView valueItemView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            valueItemView = ValueItemView_.build(context);
        } else {
            valueItemView = (ValueItemView) convertView;
        }
        valueItemView.bind(getItem(position));

        return valueItemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Value getItem(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

ValuesAdapter:

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.activity_value_item)
`enter code here`public class ValueItemView extends LinearLayout {
    @ViewById
    TextView tv_valueName;

    @ViewById
    TextView tv_valueClass;

    public ValueItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void bind(Value value) {
        tv_valueName.setText(value.getName());
        tv_valueClass.setText(value.getValueClass());
    }
}
```

ValuesActivity:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_values)
public class ValuesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @ViewById
    ListView values_lvValues;

    @Bean
    ValuesAdapter adapter;

    @AfterViews
    void bindAdapter() {
        values_lvValues.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @ItemClick
    void values_lvValuesItemClicked(Value value) {
        makeText(this, value.getName() + " " + value.getValueClass(), LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

activity_values.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFEEEE">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/values_lvValues"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:divider="#770000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This bug was fixed in AndroidAnnotations 4.3.1. What is the version you are using?

Comment: Actually I was using 4.0.0. Thank you so much, @WonderCsabo, for this answer. Now it builds successfully.